Нужна ли запятая перед словами «и в путь»?
Нужна ли запятая в первой части предложения?

Закусил удила(,) и в путь — ты ж принц, а не хрыч болотный.

Я бы, наверное, вместо запятой тире поставила, но там же тире во второй части уже есть...

Пунктуация тут зависит от контекста и от того, что вы, собственно, хотите отобразить на письме, какие эмоции показать (что интонационно подчеркнуть, какие паузы обозначить).
Можно оставить запятую (присоединение):
Закусил удила, и в путь — ты ж принц...
Можно поставить интонационное тире:
Закусил удила — и в путь! Ты ж принц...
Закусил удила и — в путь! Ты ж принц...

Закусил удила - и в путь: ты ж принц, а не хрыч болотный.

Правильно:
Закусил удила, и в пУть — // ты ж принц, а не хрыч болоОтный.
Рассматриваем авторский вариант,  без деления предложения на части.  Два сильных знака (двоеточие и тире) в одном предложении нежелательны,  иначе его не прочитаешь. Так что запятую оставляем.
Восклицательный знак можно поставить в конце предложения.
